# Pass nested object model as request paramters in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, api, model

I am trying to pass the request params using model structure in typecript. I can do if the object is not nested. But incase object is nested array like below, I am not able to assign the values and pass as request parameter.
Do let me know if anyone have any suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

```
export class exampleModel{

    products: [
        {
            name: string,
            address:string,
            product_sizes: [
                {
                    quntity: number,
                    price: number,
                    id: [
                        number
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

After creating such model I am initialzing model as below

```
  productRequestObject : exampleModel = <exampleModel>{}
```

And then trying to assign values to it

```
    this.productRequestObject.products[0].name = sessionStorage.getItem('name')
```

Here I am getting the error as `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Please let me know if I am missing anything!

Comment: If you initialize it to an empty object, then that error is expected since there isn't any product/name property.

Comment: The products array is empty. That's why you are getting this error. Try to populate some date for products and try out assigning the name for the first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize an empty object. Although you know the structure, it currently has no field `projects`. One way to do it the right way is this to predefine interfaces and models. Then you instantiate and assemble them like a puzzle according to their nested structure.

Define your interfaces in `interfaces.ts`

```
export interface IProductSize {
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
    id: Array<number>;
}

export interface IProduct {
    name: string;
    address:string;
    product_sizes: Array<IProductSize>;
}

export interface IRequest {
    products: Array<IProduct>;
}

export interface IExampleModel {
    requests: Array<IRequest>;
}
```

Having this, define your classes in `models.ts`

```
export class ProductSize implements IProductSize {
    constructor(
        public quantity: number,
        public price: number,
        public id: Array<number>){}
}

export class Product implements IProduct {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public address:string,
        public product_sizes: Array<IProductSize>){}
}

export class Request implements IRequest {
    constructor(public products: Array<IProduct>){}
}

export class ExampleModel implements IExampleModel {
    constructor(public requests: Array<IRequest>){}
}
```

Now you can go on and assemble your object.

```
let productSize: IProductSize = new ProductSize(0, 0, []);
let product: IProduct = new Product('', '', [productSize]);
let request: IRequest = new Request([product]);
let productRequestObject: IExampleModel = new ExampleModel([request]);
```

And finally you can access the field

```
 this.productRequestObject.products[0].name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
```

This is how you should do it in Angular. This way you are totally flexible and you have total control over each level of your nested construct.